# High IQ and problem solving

Tags: iq, chess

Are there any studies, which shows that High IQ people are good or average or bad in problem solving/other professions?

Need to know that High IQ correlates to very good problem solving skills or not.

Comment: Hi SzD, assuming you refer with "IQ" to somewhat like fluid intelligence, I would guess, that your question is a bit circular. The problem is, that fluid intelligence is generally referred to as a "reasoning and novel-problem solving ability" (Gray et al., 2003. p. 316: http://jtoomim.org/brain-training/neural%20mechanisms%20of%20general%20intelligence.pdf; you can also scan the book of Cattell: intelligence, it’s structure, growth and action). Thus intelligence = Problem solving … so there is tons of literature. Do you have any specific area in mind (e.g. chess)?

Comment: I'm a little confused at your question. Why is "problem solving/other professions" grouped together like that, given that problem solving is not a profession?  As @bucky said, IQ tests are generally heavily weighted toward measuring one's abilities in problem solving.